# Need warning message if count of each country code is less than 5

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get a warning or print message if count or frequency of a particular country code is less than 5.

```
QuoteID
1500759-BE
1500759-BE
1500759-BE
1500759-BE
1605101-FR
1605101-FR
1605101-FR
1605119-FR
1605119-FR
1605119-FR
1605119-FR
1605119-FR
1600896-NL
1600896-NL
1600896-NL
1600898-NL
1600898-NL
1600898-NL
1600898-NL
1600898-NL
1600898-NL
```

Tried the below code

```
chars=('BE','FR','NL')
check_string=OutputData['QuoteID']

for char in chars:
  count = check_string.count(char)
  if count < 5:
    print ('count is less than 5 )
```

expected result is - *"warning 'category BE' has less than 5 records"*

`OutputData` - Data set name  
`QuoteID` - variable name

values like `1500759-BE` is value in variable and frequency or count of 'BE', 'FR' and 'NL' has to be counted and warning message required if count is less than 5.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to check for both the ID and the country code? Could you please provide a sample snippet of the desired output of a given input? Do you want to check for less then five or less then ten occurrences since you said ten at the beginning of your question and five at the end. What is your _actual_ problem with the code you provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the country codes from each `QuoteID` string as follows:

```
In [16]: df['CountryCode'] = df['QuoteID'].str.extract('(?P<letter>BE|FR|NL)', expand=True)

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
       QuoteID CountryCode
0   1500759-BE          BE
1   1500759-BE          BE
2   1500759-BE          BE
3   1500759-BE          BE
4   1605101-FR          FR
5   1605101-FR          FR
6   1605101-FR          FR
7   1605119-FR          FR
8   1605119-FR          FR
9   1605119-FR          FR
10  1605119-FR          FR
11  1605119-FR          FR
12  1600896-NL          NL
13  1600896-NL          NL
14  1600896-NL          NL
15  1600898-NL          NL
16  1600898-NL          NL
17  1600898-NL          NL
18  1600898-NL          NL
19  1600898-NL          NL
20  1600898-NL          NL
```

By using [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to compute the counts of unique values, you could then convert the `series` object to a dictionary by calling `to_dict()` followed by a `list-comprehension` to get your desired result.

```
In [18]: ["count of %s is %d" % (key, value) if value > 5 else   \
         "WARN!: count of category %s is less than 5" % (key)    \
         for key, value in df['CountryCode'].value_counts().to_dict().items()]
Out[18]: 
['WARN!: count of category BE is less than 5',
 'count of NL is 9',
 'count of FR is 8']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Counter` provided by Python's `collections` module to count the occurrences of the elements in a list.
In addition you can extract the country codes given in your sample data by splitting all lines and strip off the last two elements of each line (which is the country code).

All in all I would suggest something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

data = """1500759-BE
1500759-BE
1500759-BE
1500759-BE
1605101-FR
1605101-FR
1605101-FR
1605119-FR
1605119-FR
1605119-FR
1605119-FR
1605119-FR
1600896-NL
1600896-NL
1600896-NL
1600898-NL
1600898-NL
1600898-NL
1600898-NL
1600898-NL
1600898-NL
"""

codes = [l[-2:] for l in data.splitlines()]

c = Counter(codes)

for k,v in c.items():
    if v < 5:
        print('less then 5 items for {}'.format(k))
```

As you tagged your question with `python-2.7` you need to keep in mind to convert the Python3 code I provided to the Python2-equivalent. That said, you need to use `print output` instead of `print(output)` and `.items()` would become `.iteritems()`.

Answer (score 0):

what is the type of QuoteID if its type is string then it works fine

```
alist = "1500759-BE1500759-BE1500759-BE1500759-BE1605101-FR1605101-FR1605101-FR1605119-FR1605119-FR1605119-FR1605119-FR1605119-FR1600896-NL1600896-NL1600896-NL1600898-NL1600898-NL1600898-NL1600898-NL1600898-NL1600898-NL"

chars=('BE','FR','NL')

for char in chars:

count = alist.count(char)

if count < 5:

    print ('count is less than 5' )

    print char

    print "\n"
```

if works fine for me